# Query database and insert new data into the table only if conditions of initial query are met

Tags: c#, wpf, string, sqlite

I'm working on a small project where the user can log into the application when the application first launches, and that works great. I wanted to add a way for users with isAdmin attribute to be able to create new accounts that can access the application.

So far, I'm searching the database table "employeeinfo" by taking the text the user enters into a textbox (this.txt_enterAdmin.Text) to decide whether the user has privileges to make more accounts, and then, if a user is present in "employeeinfo" they can then enter a new username and password into the table.

This also works great. My problem is that I don't want just any user to be able to create new accounts, I want admins, and only admins to be able to do so. I'm not sure how to search the database with a hardcoded YES/NO. I've added a column called "isAdmin" and then assigned each user a "YES" or "NO" in the SQLite data table using the "text" datatype.

Here's my code, please give it a look:

```
private void txt_add_newuser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           //logic to connect to database, search for the administrator password, and if the data is correct, then create a new user that can use the    application.

        SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);

            sqliteCon.Open();
            string YES = "select * from employeeinfo where isAdmin='" +  + "' ";
            string Query = "select * from employeeinfo where password='" + this.txt_enterAdmin.Text + "' and isAdmin= '" + this.YES + "' ";
            SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);


            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SQLiteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();

            int count = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count++;
            }
        if (count == 1)
        {

            try
            {
                SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn1;
                SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
                sqlite_conn1 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;");
                sqlite_conn1.Open();
                sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn1.CreateCommand();
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo ([username],[password]) values('" + txt_newusername.Text + "','" + txt_newPassword.Text + "' )";
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully added new user. Press OK/ENTER to Continue");
                //clears fields if new entry to database is accepted.
                if (txt_newusername != null)
                    (txt_newusername).Clear();
                if (txt_newPassword != null)
                    (txt_newPassword).Clear();
                if (txt_enterAdmin != null)
                    (txt_enterAdmin).Clear();
                sqlite_conn1.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Everything was entered correctly, but something broke. Please contact support for help.");
            }
        }
        if (count > 1)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Administrator password incorrect. Check your details and try again. Press enter to continue.");
          if (txt_enterAdmin != null)
          (txt_enterAdmin).Clear();
          sqliteCon.Close();
        }
        if (count < 1)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Administrator password incorrect. Check your details and try again. Press enter to continue.");
           if (txt_enterAdmin != null)
           (txt_enterAdmin).Clear();
           sqliteCon.Close();
        }
        sqliteCon.Close();
    }
```

I'm not sure how to define the string for YES/NO values, because I'm not pulling the data from a user-facing control.

Any feedback or any mistakes you see that I can address as well would also be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to define `string YES`? There is a `isAdmin` column in `employeeInfo` table, so select it in `Query` (actually, you already do because of `SELECT *`), then test the value YES or NO to decide how to proceed.

Another option might be to add a `WHERE isAdmin = 'YES'` to the `Query`. If no rows are returned, this user doesn't have the proper creds.

Comment: Your second solution worked great, thanks. Can you further describe how I would implement the first though? How would I test the value YES/NO without the second solution?

Comment: I don't know the particular interface, but there must be a way to get the column values returned from executing the SQL. So something like `if (count == 1 and dr.isAdmin == 'YES')`. Sorry, I don't know the interface/syntax.